# How to provide dynamic answer for the selected entity as parameter in dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: node.js, entity, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have an entity (items) and its values are ('name', 'colour', 'awards')

I have three intents

```
Intent1 = Welcome Intent (user will get the options in the form of chips)
Intent2 = Select Option (bot will ask question to enter detail for selected option)
Intent3 = Update Option (bot will save the record and ask next option to update.)

Example - 
bot: welcome! what you want to update? name, colour, awards.
user: name
bot: Enter your name.
user: John
bot: record updated, what to update next? name, colour, awards.
```

now the issue is awards have multiple fields to update, to update awards a user has to provide three things (award name, award date, award description)

What I want is when a user selects awards options from the chips then it should be taken to new intent where I will get all the data through slot filling.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to remember is that an Intent represents *what the user has said* and *not* what you are doing with what they have said. So it doesn't make sense to say that you are "going to an Intent".

Second, while slot filling seems like a good idea, it usually leads to further problems, since it doesn't handle conditional information well, or handle users if they skip around in what they want to update.

All of these are better solved by setting up a state machine where they are in the conversation, what information you need, and what they have provided so far. Based on these settings, you can prompt them yourself for what you expect next. (You may also find using one or several Dialogflow contexts useful for shaping how to accept results as well.)

So, for example, when the user has indicated they are updating the awards, it might work like this:

```
User: Awards
[Your fulfillment sets the 'awards' context with a parameter that we are prompting for the name.]
Bot: Ok, I'm going to need the award name, description, and when it was awarded. What is the name?

User: Merit
[This matches the Fallback Intent with an Input Context for 'awards', since it is free-form input. Your fulfillment stores this and sets the 'awards' context with a parameter that we are now prompting for the date.]
Bot: Got it, the award is named Merit. When was it awarded?

User: Today
[This matches an Intent with a training phrase of "<@sys.date>" and the Input Context of 'awards'. There are also training phrases for things like "It was awarded <@sys.date>" and so forth. Your fulfillment sets the date and sets the 'awards' context with a parameter that we're now prompting for description.]
Bot: Got it. Awarded on March 1st. What is the description?

User: They were awesome.
[This matches the Fallback Intent with the Input Context of 'awards' again, because it is still free-form input. Our fulfillment, however, knows that this is about the description this time, so it stores it and removes the 'awards' context since we've captured everything.]
Bot: I've recorded that as a description of "they were awesome" - sure thing. That was everything we needed for now. Do you want to update the name, colour, or awards next?
```

That all seems pretty straightforward. But consider if the conversation had gone this way:

```
User: Awards
[Your fulfillment sets the 'awards' context with a parameter that we are prompting for the name.]
Bot: Ok, I'm going to need the award name, description, and when it was awarded. What is the name?

User: [Having done this many times] They were given the award for Honor yesterday
[This might match an Intent with an Input Context of 'awards' and the training phrase of "Given the award for <@sys.any> <@sys.date>" and possibly "<@sys.date> they got an award for <@sys.any>". Your fulfillment sets the name and date from this, sees what information it still needs, and prompts with...]
Bot: Got it. Award named Honor. Awarded March 1. What is the description?

User: Actually, it is named Honorable Service
[This matches an Intent with a training phrase of "named <@sys.any>" and an Input Context for 'awards'. Your fulfillment changes the name stored, checks what we still need, and again prompts...]
Bot: Ok, I've changed the award name to Honorable Service. What is the description?
```

The first scenario could be handled by slot filling and simple prompting, but the second can't. Being able to handle more natural responses from people and more flexible prompting will be better for your users.